# Issue with constructor

Tags: c++

Currently I have a tic tac toe board "tttBoard" with a constructor

```
    tttBoard::tttBoard() {
    isX = true;
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
            gBoard[x][y]=sEmp;
        }
    }
}
```

That *should* create a new board and fill it with the enum `sEmp`. `isX` is a boolean which marks that the first player moves first. Despite having `#include "tttBoard.h"` and (I believe) having the constructor in that header file (below), I've run across the same errors over and over:

```
error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
error C2059: syntax error : '::'
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

**tttBoard.h**

```
#ifndef tttBoard
#define tttBoard

class tttBoard {
public:
tttBoard();
    void            Draw();
    void            Move(int x, int y);
    char*           getValue(int x, int y);
private:
    enum sVal {
        sEmp,
        sX,
        sO
    };

    sVal            gBoard[3][3];
    bool            isX;
}

#endif
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the class definition.

Comment: I added one to the end of the header file and got the error `warning C4094: untagged 'class' declared no symbols`, did I misunderstand? Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @Chris: Your `#define tttBoard` is screwing it up. You're replacing the token "tttBoard" with nothing, which makes your class declaration into just `class {`

Comment: @KevinBallard how should I change the #define? Removing it results in a `error C2011: 'tttBoard' : 'class' type redefinition`

Comment: @Chris: Use a different name for your define. Maybe `ttt_Board_GUARD` or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#ifndef tttBoard
#define tttBoard

class tttBoard {
```

That's not a proper include guard.  You're defining `tttBoard` as an empty symbol and then using the same name for the class.

```
#ifndef TTT_BOARD_H
#define TTT_BOARD_H

class tttBoard { 
    // stuff
};

#endif
```